# wso2 appm issue with ldap authentication when login on store or publisher

Tags: ldap, wso2

I'm trying to use wso2 APPM (vers 1.10.0) with an external ldap as authentication without real success.

I'll try to be as factual as possible to let it be testable:

1. I've unzip the wso2appm zip file under linux
2. I've setup the java_home var
3. I've start the wso2server.sh ==> no problem displayed in the log, at this step I must precise I'm using the default database of wso2.
4. Then logging to carbon gui, and adding a new userstore management setting up to a read-only external ldap.
5. after few seconds, the ldap users appears in the user list.
6. then selecting me in the list and adding the internal/store role.
7. opening the store url, and trying to login with the login / password of my user

Then having a message to inform me that the user has not the store profile.

If I log into carbon with my ldap user, it's working.

The same use case with the API looks fine to log into the store.

Any fix or ideas are welcome.

BR,

jfv

Comment: Are you using [WSO2 API Manager](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/) or [WSO2 App Manager](http://wso2.com/products/app-manager/)? And, Can you post the error message you are getting while log in?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it I suspect your issue is, the privileges are not set correctly for your ldap user store roles. Please make sure that you have assigned the internal/subscriber role to the relevant user in your permission tree. You can find more details about this at JIRA ticket [1]

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APPM-279

Cheers,
Pubudu

Answer (score 0):

Hi and thank your for your answer,

first: I've checked this morning the solution you've proposed, and  there is no change.
In a second time, I've tryied to add all privileges without more success
but if I create a new user manually, this one can login.

The following error in the log are shown when I try to login with an ldap user.

[2016-05-09 07:48:54,272]  INFO - ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager LDAP connection created successfully in read-only mode
[2016-05-09 07:48:54,283]  INFO - UserStoreDeploymentManager Realm configuration of tenant:-1234  modified with /opt/wso2appm/repository/deployment/server/userstores/orange_com.xml
[2016-05-09 07:50:18,187]  WARN - CarbonAuthenticationUtil Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2016-05-09 07:50:18,187+0200]
[2016-05-09 07:50:18,189]  WARN - AuthenticationHandler Illegal access attempt at [2016-05-09 07:50:18,0188] from IP address 10.199.210.37 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2016-05-09 07:50:18,189] ERROR - AUDIT_LOG Illegal access attempt at [2016-05-09 07:50:18,0188] from IP address 10.199.210.37 while trying to authenticate access to service RemoteAuthorizationManagerService
[2016-05-09 07:50:18,221]  WARN - acs:jag User jaav7491 does not have permission to access the store application. Make sure the user has the store role.

the login is "jaav7491"
Thank you for your ideas,

BR,

jfv

Comment: A minor precision: the ldap user can login into carbon.